# How to deploy existing Spring MVC + JPA + MYSql + Maven app , in Google cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an exiting web application with the following configs :-

- Spring MVC
- JPA
- MySql DB
- Maven
- JBoss7

This application is up an running in my local env successfully. I now want to deploy this application as it is in "Google cloud" platform. 
How can I achieve this ?

I have tried these tutorials on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating their website, but most of them talks about a very basic application setup.

I just need the step by step process to pushi this whole application to Google cloud. I have already created a Google cloud account, have an app and app_id setup. so the basic stuff is done from end.

-- Sumit

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial you have linked to is for the Google AppEngine.  Only Spring MVC and Maven (and JPA to a limited extent) from your chosen stack will work on the Google AppEngine.  MySQL and JBoss are not supported.  If you wish to use these, you should use the Google Compute Engine to launch your own virtual servers on the Google Cloud and then configure them according to your needs.

Google AppEngine is a [Platform-as-a-Service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine) offering, which provides a limited runtime environment for Java applications.  It is similar to application containers like JBoss, but is quite [limited in scope](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/).  It allows developers to run Servlet based applications.  Therefore, in essence, AppEngine is a substitute for the likes of JBoss, which is why one cannot use JBoss (or Weblogic or Websphere) on the AppEngine.

AppEngine provides a [few ways to store data](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/storage), one of which is a [relational SQL data store](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction) based on MySQL.  This store [can be accessed using JPA](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2) but with restrictions (based on my experience).

The key thing to note is that AppEngine provides a `sandboxed` environment for Java applications, which puts several restrictions on the applications.  In addition, getting an application to work correctly on AppEngine can take some time, working through the issues posed by the runtime environment.  If these are not an issue for you, AppEngine can be a good fit for your requirements.  If however, you want greater control over your deployment and more flexibility in the software used, you should look at Google Compute Engine or other Cloud offerings.